# HP Microserver Gen8 RAID0 rebuild loss data

Tags: raid, hp, data-recovery, raid0

I have 2 WD HDD on gen8 and built as RAID0 on slot1 and slot2, and I have unplugged this two disk and install seagate disk on slot 1 and slot 2. and SmartArray report there are no raid found.
then I create an raid0 for seagate disk in slot 1 and slot 2.
when I removed the seagate disk , and re install WD HDD ( I can't remember squence, which in slot1 and which in slot 2)
I enter the SmartArray configure, and I can see this two WD HDD was in physical mode, not array mode. (this take a short time)
I clieck create disk as raid0 for this two disk, and in windows I saw an empty disk.

Does all data on WD HDD lose? And can I recovery data on this two disk?

(the Raid Card is B120i on Board.)

Answer (score 6):

So lets see if I got this straight:

- You had two Western Digital HDDs in a RAID 0 array.
- You removed them and replaced them with some Seagate HDDs, and created a new RAID 0 array.
- You then replaced the Western Digital HDDs, possibly in a different order to the one they were in originally, and created a brand new RAID 0 array.

Have I missed anything? What you've done is broadly speaking, the IT equivalent of punching yourself in the face while asking "does this hurt? how about now?" repeatedly.

Your data more than likely is gone, from those disks anyway. RAID 0 is [dangerous at the best of times](https://superuser.com/questions/65355/is-raid-0-as-risky-as-people-say-it-is) and what you've done hardly qualifies as 'the best of times'.

You should *always* be backing up data before changing the physical disks around in a RAID array (you should be backing up data you care about *anyway* of course) and this kind of mess-up is why.

Comment: yes, the disk was replaced in slot , and I've never do DELETE ARRAY in HP raid config program, (only execute DELETE ARRAY , that the program notice me data lose, and it not noticed me data lose when I CREATE ARRAY). Now I can read some file with DiskGenius(a HDD recovery software) , some files can be copied out, and fine, but some big file can't be copied out), does it mean that data can be recovery?